# Share module across all modules of wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

Add custom module dependency across all the system/layer/base jboss modules and all custom modules.

I have added the module dependency in `<global-modules/>` in `standalone-full.xml` but I guess its only for custom modules as I need to add it manually in module.xml of all the system/layer/base module.

Is there a way to expose one module to all modules?

Comment: why would you need to add a module dependency to all modules of wildfly? it sounds strange

Comment: i was trying to add ELK javaagent to wildfly. So in startup its asking the dependencies on many wildfly modules